# How to free memory allocated to a drawables before activity exits?

Tags: java, android

```
public class PageActivity extends Activity {
private int numPages = 31;
private TouchImageView[] imageViews = new TouchImageView[numPages];
private String URL = "http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/201108";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        imageViews[i] = new TouchImageView(this);
        imageViews[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);
        imageViews[i].setMaxZoom(4f);
    }

    setContentView(viewPager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
}


private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numPages;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((TouchImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = PageActivity.this;

        String pageURL = URL;

        if (imageViews[position].getDrawable() == null) {
            ImageFetcher imagefetcher = new ImageFetcher();
            imagefetcher.execute(
                    pageURL + String.format("%02d", position+1) + ".gif",
                    String.valueOf(position+1));
        }


        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageViews[position], 0);
        return imageViews[position];
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((TouchImageView) object);
                    imageViews[position].removeCallbacks(null);

    }

}
public class ImageFetcher extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Drawable> {
    int fillthisPos;

    public Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(urls[0]).getContent();
            fillthisPos = Integer.parseInt(urls[1]);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageViews[fillthisPos].setImageDrawable(result);
        result = null;
    }

}
```

}

I am trying to create an image viewer which can load images from given URLs.The code above implement this using

- TouchImageView for touch handling on single image.
- ViewPager and PageAdapter to let user move to next page.
- Asyn Tasks to download the image when a page is instantiated.

When i have downloaded some images , the app crashes. I checked from DDMS/MAT that the Bitmaps for the images are not being freed  . It is because the views i am destroying are not being collected by GC as they are being still referenced somewhere.

I was wondering if their is some way to explicitly free up the memory in such cases? I tried removing all references from my code but it still doesn't release the memory.

PS: excuse me for putting up the code first , i tried to move it down but the formatting gets messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to keep an array of `ImageFetcher` tasks. By doing this, you are maintaining references to the loaded drawables. Try eliminating the array from your code. The `AsyncTask`s will run to completion without you needing to maintain references to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , yes it did work without the array , but from DDMS i still see the memory getting increased in same pattern which eventually causes the crash once the heap limit gets crossed.I will update the code in my question to show the stiuation now.

Comment: @ManikMahajan - Well, the way you've set things up with an array of `TouchImageView`, each holding a drawable, it will try to retain all the loaded images in memory. Do you really need 31 `TouchImageView` objects? Perhaps you could reuse a single one?

Comment: I need atleast 3 as to allow page flipping, Is there a way i can free up old ones in destroyItem ? i tried adding imageViews[position].removeCallbacks(null);  but still no affect on memory usage.

Comment: @ManikMahajan - You can try calling `setImageDrawable(null)`.